# Can't give an automatic height to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have got this following UITableView in my code

```
tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0))
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return comments.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier") as UITableViewCell!

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.comments[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:bottomView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
```

I was also advised to add bottom anchor, but I didn't know where to add them and I want to give an automatic height to this UITableView. I tried two things

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: tableView.contentSize.height).isActive = true
```

And none of them worked.

Comment: automatic height for tableview or cell?

Comment: @TusharSharma for tableview

Comment: what is UI that you want to achieve?

Comment: @TusharSharma i want my tableview to automatically resize based on it's contentsize

Comment: i want just ask you have  cell size fixed or not?

Comment: @UmeshVerma no it's not

Comment: @TusharSharma my `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is not set thus it's 0

Comment: @TusharSharma thanks for helping.That didn't help

Comment: @TusharSharma you ruined everything

Comment: @sakoaskoaso happy now .

Comment: @TusharSharma no

Comment: @sakoaskoaso not my headache man i shared a link to help you and you showing me attitude here . I deleted one continue with question there are many other who can help you be patient.

Comment: Please don't duplicate your own questions.